Does this sequence contain infinitely many holeless numbers?
Let's define a sequence based on number of holes in a number. $1, 2, 3, 5, 7$ contain no hole, $0, 4, 6, 9$ contain 1 hole, and $8$ contains 2 holes. So as an example, $681$ contains $1+2+0=3$ holes.  Then, i define a sequence starting with $4$. The next term is computed by adding the previous term with the number of holes in the sequence so far. So the sequence goes as follow:
$$4, 5, 6, 8, 12, 16, 21, 26, 32, 38, 46,...$$
Then, I look at the holeless numbers in the sequence
$$5,12,21,32,122,175,215,337,757,1215,2152,2531,3713,7725,...$$
They are relatively common and I expect there are infinitely many of them, but can anyone prove it?

+1 : for your posted question, which I find to be bizarre but interesting.  Normally, I would have gone the other way and considered criticizing the posted question, in accordance with this article on MathSE protocol.  That is, you showed no work, did not describe either the source of the problem or your math education, and did not suggest any tools that might be used to attack the problem.  ...see next comment

However, for this bizarre question, I went the other way.  Presumably, no book/class assigned this problem, and it is reasonable to assume that you haven't been given any specific tools (if such tools even exist) with which to analytically attack the problem.  So, I don't really care about your math education, or whether you or someone else originated the problem.  My reaction is therefore based on the idea that the problem strikes me as interesting.  Also, I found your presentation of the problem to be very clear, which I find refreshing.

$0,2×2,2×3,2^3,3×3$ Hmm we can make something that can recognise these. Let the $hole$ counter be named as $i$. For $0$ it's fixed to be $1$. For other digits, it's (number of terms in its prime factorisation -1) This thing even works for holeless digits.

This time I agree , the idea is strange , but the problem itself interesting. We need more such problems , therefore to encourage them (+1). A reformulation of the numbers that are considered is that all digits must be $1$ or prime.

+1 for the interesting question. But I can't help feeling a little disappointed, "unholy number" was right there!

Not an answer, just some musings on orders of growth.
Let $(a_k)_{k = 1, 2, 3, ...} = (4, 5, 6, 8, 12, ...)$ denote the first sequence.
Let $d_k = $ the number of digits of $a_k$, and $h_k = $ the number of holes of $a_k$.

Conjecture 1: $a_k$ grows less than $k^3$

Consider $a_k$.  By this time, $h_1$ has been added $k-1$ times, $h_2$ has been added $k-2$ times, etc.  So we have
$$a_k = 4 + (k-1)h_1 + (k-2) h_2 + ... + h_{k-1}$$
We now introduce two approximations: If the digits were random, the average number of holes per digit would be about $1/2$ (not exactly, because $8$ has two holes, and because $0$ is never a leading digit).  So we approximate $h_k \approx d_k / 2$.  Combining with $d_j \le d_{j+1}$ and we have:
$$a_k \lt 4 + \frac{k(k-1)}{2} \frac{d_k}{2}$$
(Alternatively we can use the non-approximation $h_k \le 2 d_k$ to arrive at a looser bound $a_k \lt 4 + k(k-1)d_k$.)
Since $d_k = 1 + \lfloor \log_{10} a_k \rfloor$, this implies $a_k$ grows less than $k^3$.  (I am actually not sure this is rigorous...?  Any help on this point would be much appreciated.)

Conjecture 2: There are infinitely many holeless numbers in $a_k$ sequence.

Now consider all $61$-digit numbers, i.e. the range $10^{60}$ to $10^{61}-1$.  Suppose $a_k = k^3$ for now.  The first such $k$ that puts $a_k$ in range is $10^{20}$ and the last such $k \approx t \times 10^{20}$ where $t = 10^{1/3} \approx 2.15$.  Thus there are $\approx (t-1) \times 10^{20}$ such $a_k$ in the range.  If $a_k$ actually grows slower than $k^3$ then there will be even more in range.
Again assuming digits are random, the probability that a $61$-digit number is holeless $\approx 2^{-61}$.  So the probability ALL the in-range $a_k$'s have holes (i.e., none of them is holeless) is
$$P_{61} = (1 - 2^{-61})^{(t-1) \times 10^{20}}$$
and $P_{61} \approx 2 \times 10^{-22}$ per Wolfram Alpha.  Ultimately, this is because $(1 - 1/n)^n \to 1/e$, but in our case the "expected" number of holeless $a_k$'s in range is $E_{3n+1} \approx (t - 1) \times 10^n \times 2^{-3n-1} = \frac{t-1}{2} \times (\frac{10}{8})^n \to \infty$ and so $P_{3n+1} \to (1/e)^{E_{3n+1}} \to 0$.
Based on these heuristic, randomized reasoning, it seems there will in fact be many holeless numbers of any given "size" as defined by number of digits.
